# Java "partial" override

Tags: java, overriding

When overriding a method in Java is it possible to call the "original" one. For example:

```
public class A extends B{

  @Override
  public void foo(){
    System.out.println("yep");
    // Then execute foo() as it's defined in B
  }

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
public class A extends B{

  @Override
  public void foo(){
    System.out.println("yep");
    super.foo(); // calls the method implemented in B
  }  
}
```

Comment: The tick goes to the fast gun. For some reason I had misunderstood the use of super

Comment: @DrDro: you might not have misunderstood it, because this is not the only use of `super`.

Answer (score 7):

Simply call `super.methodName()` to call your supertype's version of the method.

```
public class A extends B{
  @Override
  public void foo(){
    System.out.println("yep");
    super.foo(); // Here you call the supertype's foo()
  }
}
```

Also, this isn't 'partially' overriding the method.  You are fully overriding it, but you are just using some of the parent's functionality.

Answer (score 3):

The use of the Keywork [super](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) is meant for this

```
super.foo();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `super.foo()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can call

```
super.foo();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
super.foo()
```